# Flutter Realm: Update Realm Object

Tags: database, flutter, realm

I'm trying to usé Realm database un à flutter project. How to update an entier object? It is hard to do it property by property.

Comment: Which package are you using? Please specify exact name package name & link. Also, Please share some piece of code of what you've achieved so far for better understanding of your problem.

Comment: Hello and thx for for your reaction. I'm using the official [realm SDK](https://pub.dev/packages/realm).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution:It consists of adding setting `update = true` in `add` method.

```
realmDb.write<ObjectModel>(() => realmDb.add<ObjectModel>(newValue, update: true));
```